# data.table in R: Count if with multiple criteria between 2 data.tables

Tags: r, join, data.table

**Story**

I am trying to add information about count of changes done on vendor (stored in Table 2) to my main set of data (stored in Table 1).

I am finding it difficult to connect counting of T2 elements with creation of column in T1.

**Example**

Example of counting for single vendor and specified field name might look like this and works properly:

```
nrow(T2[Vendor == 101337 & Field.Name == "Deletion flag" & Date >= 42403 & Date <= 42527]
```

**Issue**

What I find tricky is how to pass Vendor id from T1 during nrow command when I am creating new column in T1. Logically I am trying to create new column that consist of above command but instead of specified vendor (and dates) I am trying to use Vendor from T1.

```
T1[, Deletion_Flag_N := nrow(T2[Vendor == T1$Vendor & Field.Name == "Deletion flag" & Date >= T1$Doc..Date & Date <= T1$Clearing])]
```

Of course it is not working. Any idea?

**Alternative**

I am also thinking about separate temp table where I will have vendor, date and count of specific changes done on that period of time. Then I have a question how to make join based not only on vendor but also on date (it has to be between value of 2 other fields from T1)

```
    T2[Field.Name == "Deletion flag"][, .(Vendor, Date)][, .N ,by = list(Vendor, Date)]

   Vendor  Date N
1: 106724 42492 2
2: 105172 42537 1
3: 101215 42432 1
```

*Thank you for any suggestions!*

**Data used:**

Table 1

```
> head(T1[, .(ID, Vendor, Doc..Date, Clearing)])
                    ID Vendor Doc..Date Clearing
1: 1900000276_107_2016 107393     42403    42527
2: 1900000569_107_2016 107393     42494    42527
3: 1700000117_107_2016 107394     42499    42499
4: 1700000120_107_2016 107394     42397    42517
5: 1900000442_107_2016 107394     42397    42517
6: 1900000501_107_2016 107607     42474    42513
```

Table 2

```
> head(T2[, .(Vendor, Field.Name, Date, New.value)])
   Vendor Field.Name  Date New.value
1: 101337 Payt Terms 42626      45DN
2: 101337 Payt Terms 42626      45DN
3: 136370 Payt Terms 42611      60DN
4: 107047 Payt Terms 42580      90DN
5: 101337 Payt Terms 42569      45DN
6: 136370 Payt Terms 42558      60DN
```

Comment: Why are you using `nrow` at all? For first example, this should work `T2[Vendor == 101337 & Field.Name == "Deletion flag" & Date >= 42403 & Date <= 42527, .N]`. For the second example: `T1[, Deletion_Flag_N := length(vendor_changes[Vendor == T1$Vendor & Field.Name == "Deletion flag" & Date >= T1$Doc..Date & Date <= T1$Clearing])]` or even `T1[, Deletion_Flag_N := sum(Vendor == T1$Vendor & Field.Name == "Deletion flag" & Date >= T1$Doc..Date & Date <= T1$Clearing)]`. Also it seems that you should have `T2` there instead of `T1`? I'm kind of confused with your second example

Comment: At beginning nrow was enough but .N is indeed better.

Both example they are not working.

T1 has information about document, which I am trying to enrich with T2 data.

T2 has information about vendor changes by time. 

I am trying to add to T1 information about count of specific changes (stored in T2).

To make clear where we have information I edited my example:

T1[, Deletion_Flag_N := T2[T2$Vendor == T1$Vendor & T2$Field.Name == "Deletion flag" & T2$Date >= T1$Doc..Date & T2$Date <= T1$Clearing, .N]]

Error: Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: You probably want `T2[Field.Name == "Deletion flag"][T1, on = .(Vendor, Date >= Doc..Date, Date <= Clearing), .N, by = .EACHI]`. You'll need the latest devel version. Obviously untested, since OP *doesn't have* a minimal reproducible example.